# Extracting Data From a Pandas object to put into JIRA

Tags: python, pandas, jira, data-analysis

df is an object created by pandas which contains 13 columns of data that I want to input just data from two columns into JIRA by creating new issues. It is a 272X13 object. Each column represents a different field for an issue in JIRA. Every new issue created in JIRA should get info from just two columns in df: Summary and Comments.

How do I extract every value from the two columns as I go through each row in a for loop? I only want the string values from each row and column, no index, no object. My code is below:

```python
from jira.client import JIRA
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Python27\\scripts\\export.csv')

# Set the column names from the export.csv file equal to variables using the      
# pandas python module

# Loop to create new issues

for row in df.iterrows():
summ = str(df.loc[row.index, 'Summary'])[:30]
comments = str(df.loc[row.index, 'Comments'])
jira.create_issue(project={'key': 'DEL'}, summary=summ, description=comments, issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})
```

When I do this I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\JIRAprocess_Delta.py",    line 86, in <module>
summ = str(df.loc[row.index, 'Summary'])[:30]
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 669, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_tuple(key)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 252, in _getitem_tuple
return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 361, in _getitem_lowerdim
section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 758, in _getitem_axis
return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 60, in _get_label
return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis, copy=True)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2281, in xs
loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\index.py", line 755, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(key)
File "index.pyx", line 130, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3238)
File "index.pyx", line 147, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3085)
File "index.pyx", line 293, in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas\index.c:5393)
File "C:\Python27\CQPython\cqpython-read-only\src\clearquest\pandas\core\series.py", line 523, in __hash__
raise TypeError('unhashable type')
TypeError: unhashable type
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Here is some example data that is showing up in JIRA for every single issue created in the comments field:

Issue 1:

 0 NaN 

 1 Found that the Delta would leak packets receiv... 

 2 The Delta will reset everytime you disconnect ...

 3 NaN

 4 It's supposed to get logged when CP takes to l...

 5 Upon upgrading the IDS via the BioMed menu, th...

 6 Upon upgrading the IDS via the BioMed menu, th...

 7 Upon upgrading the IDS via the BioMed menu, th...

 8 Increased Fusion heap size and the SCC1 Initia...

 9 Recheck using build 142+, after Matt delivers ...

 10 When using WPA2, there is EAPOL key echange go...

 11 When using WPA2, there is EAPOL key echange go...

 12 NaN

 13 NaN

 14 NaN

 ...

I only want each issue to have its own string values, and not the index numbers or the NaN to show up like this:

Issue 1:  

 Issue 2: Found that the Delta would leak packets receiv... 

 Issue 3: The Delta will reset everytime you disconnect ...

 ...

Comment: Perhaps post the full traceback.  For this problem, something like df.apply(jira.create_issue) should work.  You'll pass the args and kwargs as noted in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply).  If you post some sample data I could help you more.

Comment: @TomAugspurger I posted the full traceback, it doesn't like the summ = ...line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the use of iterrows.

From the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), the function df.iterrows() iterate over DataFrame rows as **(index, Series) pairs**.

What you need is to replace row.index with "row[0]" which gives you the index of the dataframe you are iterating over

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    summ = str(df.loc[row[0], 'Summary'])[:30]
    comments = str(df.loc[row[0], 'Comments'])
```

By the way, I think you don't need iterrows at all:

```
for row_index in df.index:
    summ = str(df.loc[row_index, 'Summary'])[:30]
    comments = str(df.loc[row_index, 'Comments'])
```